# How to access in folder images in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So in my project I have folder /Pictures and everything else is all over the project folder. My problem is that I can access all the CSS , JS, HTML, but it doesn't let me get this image folder as a source of the web app.

I tried this(doesn't work):

```
  app.get('/water.jpeg', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + "Pictures" + '/' + "water.jpeg");
  });
```

I want all my images from the /Pictures folder to be a source for my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by Quora here, thanks to everyone who helped :) :
[link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-call-an-image-from-the-existing-folder-using-Node-JS-and-display-on-the-front-end)

Answer (score 5):

if image uploads to '/uploads' folder then try like

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(process.cwd() + '/uploads'))
```

Answer (score 0):

__dirname gives you the directory name of entry point file. I don't know where is your entry point file in your application, but that's where you have to start.

By the way, I advise you to use the "join" function of the "path" module to concatenate the path so as it works on linux or window filesystem.

Comment: Can you explain that in code, because I'm pretty new to node.js. Thank you so much for the advice.

Comment: @MartinDavidov include "path" module, and change your code to `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , "Pictures" , "water.jpeg"));`

Comment: @SlawomirWozniak Tried it, still won't load the image. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: @MartinDavidov Please console.log `path.join(__dirname , "Pictures" , "water.jpeg")`, and check if path is correct.